# the topic name must not contain any wildcard characters # + mqttv3-1.0.2

Tags: java, eclipse, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

i am using eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.0.2.jar to subscribe and publish data 
i need to subscribe to multiple level of topics, according to http://mosquitto.org/man/mqtt-7.html we can use some wildcard option to subscribe all remaining levels of hierarchy.
but when i try with mqttv3-1.0.2.jar i got an exception 
the topic name must not contain any wildcard characters # +
with the following code:

```
String myTopicACK = "DATA/#";
int subQoS = 2;
myClient.subscribe(myTopicACK, subQoS);
```

i also tried with topic "DATA/*"
somewhere i read that * is used for one level hierarchy.
but no success.

Exception is

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The topic name MUST NOT contain any wildcard characters (#+)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttTopic.validate(MqttTopic.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttAsyncClient.getTopic(MqttAsyncClient.java:637)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.getTopic(MqttClient.java:429)
    at PublishMe.runClient(PublishMe.java:154)
    at PublishMe.main(PublishMe.java:100)
```

Comment: The single level wildcard is '+'. Please update the question with the actual exception message so we can see all the details

Comment: Are you sure you're not trying to publish? Should be the correct syntax for subscriptions: `topicFilter` details in [`IMqttClient#subscribe(String[], int[])`](http://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/javadoc/org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/IMqttClient.html#subscribe%28java.lang.String[],%20int[]%29)

Comment: no i am trying to subscribe not publish

Comment: Line 154 from PublishMe is `myClient.subscribe(myTopicACK, subQoS);` ?

Comment: @hardillb no no it was not line 154, sorry its my fault thanks i just copy/paste the code and didn't read the exception carefully, thanks for pointing out the mistake, thanks a lot.

Comment: @hardillb one more thing i need to know that if client  subscribed a topic with Qos 2 and client received the message than automatic acknowledge will be made by client to broker  or client need to acknowledge separately the broker, if yes then how should client can acknowledge the broker

Comment: Don't use comments to ask new questions

Comment: ok sir i will ask in new question